# Listview and SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to display a ListView of all contacts and enable the user to select multiple records. I want to use ListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE) but I'm not sure how to apply it here.  The code below pulls up a list of contacts but I can't select from it.

Any tips very much appreciated

Cheers

```
public class addContacts extends ListActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_contacts);


    Uri allContacts = Uri.parse("content://contacts/people");
    Cursor c = managedQuery(allContacts, null, null, null, null);

    String[] columns = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID };
    int[] views = new int[] { R.id.contactName, R.id.contactID };

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.add_contacts, c, columns, views);
    this.setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a ListActivity you can fetch the ListView with `getListView()`, use:

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

---

But I noticed that you are using the layouts incorrectly:

```
setContentView(R.layout.add_contacts);
...
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        R.layout.add_contacts, c, columns, views);
```

Understand that:

- The layout passed to `setContentView()` should have a ListView with the id `android:id="@android:id/list"`.
- The row layout passed to SimpleCursorAdapter should *never* have a ListView... You are trying to create a ListView with ListViews on every row.

---

Try using built in layouts like this:

```
public class addContacts extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Uri allContacts = Uri.parse("content://contacts/people");
        Cursor c = managedQuery(allContacts, null, null, null, null);

        String[] columns = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID };
        int[] views = new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c, columns, views);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about built in layouts - just for future reference turns out for this job I needed simple_list_item_checked rather than simple_list_item_2, but problem solved anyway - thanks so much